# Iterating through map makes app crash

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary, iterator

I am having trouble with my code. I have created a map to store projectiles and the projectiles' IDs. When the player shoots, it creates a new Projectile in the map. When the projectile gets out of the screen, it is deleted and I am using iterators to delete the pointer towards a projectile and it erases the two elements(the projectile's ID and the pointer towards the projectile). I can run the program perfectly but when I shoot (which calls the function and creates a new projectile... When it iterates, the app crashes with the error:

```
Expression: map/set erase iterator outside range
```

I have created a typedef for the map:

```
typedef std::map<int, class Projectile*> ProjMap;
```

Here is the code:

```
void Player::destroyProjectile(Projectile *p)
{
    std::cout << "Deleting projectile with ID "<< p->getProjectileNum() << std::endl;

    //Iterating through the map
    for (ProjMap::iterator it = projectiles.begin(); it != projectiles.end(); it++)//It crashes here
    {
        if (it->first == p->getProjectileNum()){
            delete it->second;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    //Deleteing the two elements
    projectiles.erase(projectiles.find(p->getProjectileNum()));
    std::cout << "Projectiles size: " << projectiles.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the error says "map/set *erase* iterator outside range". It's actually crashing at the call to `erase`.

The problem is that you've already destroyed the `Projectile` object. Then you're attempting to do `p->getProjectileNum()` to pass to `find`. You will need to store the result of `p->getProjectileNum()` earlier and then use it to find the appropriate element of the map to erase.

A side note: if you already have a pointer to the `Projectile`, why both iterating through the map to find it? You could just do `delete p;`. I'm assuming that a projectile number is unique to each `Projectile`. And if this is the case, you can just do the `erase` and then do `delete p;`.